# How do I add a <span> or <br> to a title in Hugo?

Tags: markdown, blogs, hugo

```
---
title: This is a really long heading
section: '/'
date: 2019-08-10T18:58:32+01:00
draft: true
---
```

How do I add a break before "long" or add a `<span>` element to the markdown title in Hugo for e.g. `<span>long heading</span>` or `This is a really <br>long heading`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include a `<br>` in your title, e.g.

```
---
title: This is a really<br>long heading
---
```

you must mark the value as [safe](https://gohugo.io/functions/safehtml/) in your template, e.g.

```
{{- .Title | safeHTML -}}
```

Note that this does expose you to potential security risks:

> It should not be used for HTML from a third-party, or HTML with unclosed tags or comments.

Make sure you only do this with well-formed content you trust.

You'll have to make this change everywhere your title is shown in your theme. If there are places where you don't want the title to break, e.g. in your `list.html`, you can strip the HTML out with [`plainify`](https://gohugo.io/functions/plainify/) instead:

```
{{- .Title | plainify -}}
```

This prevents `<br>` from being shown literally.

Comment: Okay thanks. I've noticed that this adds a <span> to the site title, is it possible to stop this?

Comment: I don't see that on my machine: `<h1 class="f1 athelas mb1">My first<br>post</h1>`.

Comment: Sorry, my title in the markdown file is <h1 class="site-title">This is a really<span class="nowrap>long heading</span>. I am using a white-space:nowrap class.

The issue is that the title of the site seems to be taking in the html elements as well, so for e.g. on Google you would see the html elements like <span> or <br>.

Comment: Just wondering if this is a bug with Hugo? It doesn't show on Google search results but shows on the Google Images search results page, or in the title of a tab in the browser.